# Is there a way to list all configurable `alternatives` (symlinks for similar commands) on the system?

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora

The `alternatives` command (package `chkconfig`) on RHEL/Fedora manages symlinks which link a generic name to one of the alternative implementations. For example, `mta` group of symlinks can be provided by Sendmail and Postfix (to implement i.e. `sendmail` command):

```
alternatives --display mta
```

While I can `--display` a group of symlinks, I need to guess its name first (i.e. `mta`).

**Can I simply list all possible configurable symlink groups (like `mta`) to pick from?**

The reason is that I forget some group names occasionally.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The exact answer is (RHEL):

```
ls /var/lib/alternatives
```

---

Directory `/etc/alternatives` maintains flat long list of all symlinks *mixing* masters and slaves together. Slave symlinks cannot be used with `alternatives --display [symlink]` command.

At the same time directory `/var/lib/alternatives` contains status information (including master-slave relationship) for each group in *shortened* list of file names *all* of which can be directly used with `--display` option. For example, `/var/lib/alternatives/java`:

```
alternatives --display java
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, there is no `/var/lib/alternatives`, it seems to be `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks! One addition: on Debian and Armbian it's `/etc/alternatives` instead of `/var/lib/alternatives`

Answer (score 52):

On Debian (but not Fedora or RHEL), to see a list of all "master alternative names":

```
update-alternatives --get-selections
```

> `--get-selections` list master alternative names and their status.

And for each of those listed, you can run `--list $ALTERNATIVE_NAME`, e.g.

```
update-alternatives --list editor
```

> `--list name` Display all targets of the link group.

If you would like to see a list of all alternatives in their respective groups, you could run the following in `fish` shell:

```
for alternative in (update-alternatives --get-selections)
    echo $alternative 
    update-alternatives --list (echo $alternative | cut -d" " -f1)
    echo
end | pager
```

The (ba|z)?sh syntax should be something similar.

To change the alternatives, run `sudo update-alternatives --config $ALTERNATIVE_NAME`

Comment: On my Fedora 12 `update-alternatives` is a symlink to `alternatives`: `/usr/sbin/update-alternatives -> alternatives`. So, option `--get-selections` does not show anything (exit with error showing usage).

Comment: I didn't read the question properly. Sorry. This is for Debian. I was trying to find the same thing as you and I can't up with this answer. I wonder if I should delete my answer?

Comment: Up to you. If you think it is correct under some circumstances and might be useful for anyone else, it is worth to just leave it.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest answer would be...

```
ls /etc/alternatives
```

Comment: It's always more obvious when you already know the answer :)

Comment: It was also my first guess. But it didn't satisfy me. The list is too long containing master and slave links altogether.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 (may be some prior versions too, to be checked) and probably Debian too (to be checked):

```
ls /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives
```

List it just to get configurable alternative names, as entries in this directories are not links. By the way, there may be compressed file in this directory, so the names listed there, can't always be used as‑is. Ex. I have a `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/psql.1.gz`

Comment: Not really helpful, as the question clearly states that it applies to RedHat Enterprise Linux. The RHEL way of configuring is properly described in the other answers.